# Assigning BLANK/NULL value for Date field in Marketing cloud - Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, landing-page

I'm trying to add/update a record in data extension. When assigning null value to date field, that gives instead of emptying the field i get '1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM' value.

any idea??

Is that mandatory to store a value for date field, even if it's null-able field and not having default value assign?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mandatory and expected behavior.

As SFMC data extensions are based off SQL tables, the [date/time field types have an auto-assigned default value](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql). By having it empty, the system will default to this value (1/1/1900 12:00:00AM) as required for the field type.

Comment: But if I import data (using csv file) without date value for date fields. Its will allow. Why?  Any Idea ?

Comment: Basically there are two 'processes'  1. SFMC  - which is what you are describing and it lets it through with null/empy. 2. SQL requirements - which is what I was displaying above. Which will insert the default value into Date/Time fields if blank.

Comment: Is there any ways store a blank/null in date field . If  Customer doesn't know that date or  not willing to share that.

Comment: Only if you do not have it set to date/time.  If you set it to a text field type, it will allow it to be null, but you will lose all capabilities associated with date/time field type.  You can always use this value as an 'empty proxy' basically instead of X is EMPTY, you can have X = '1/1/1900 12:00:00AM'

Comment: Does this hold true if the database "update" is from a CloudPages form, since it's also part of SFMC and not uniquely SQL?

Comment: All things housed in Data Extensions (and I believe lists as well, but not 100% positive) inside SFMC hold to this rule. If it is stored outside of those locations, then I cannot say for certain.